# Facing Memory Issue while parsing XML using ELEMNTREE and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I am Trying to Parse and XML using beautifulsoup and elementree but its resulting in my PC getting crashed as the XML file is 15,98,040KB in size, is it possible to parse such a huge file ??? or any problems with the code ?

**XML FILE Example**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2023-12-20T16:11:15.000+05:30" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">InternalValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-1" id="14823863">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277215</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">16</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-131" id="14823714">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277240</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">18</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">0</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-132" id="14823717">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277227</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">18</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">0</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-17" id="14823804">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277552</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">16</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">0</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-173" id="14823810">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277234</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">1</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">0</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-180" id="45703377">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277572</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">2</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">0</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-91" id="14823899">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">28495</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">49</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-92" id="14823900">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">22523</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">22</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-93" id="14823901">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">8612</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">49</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-94" id="14823903">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">26480</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">36</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-95" id="14823887">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">7948</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">16</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-96" id="14823888">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">32</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">50</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

**Expected Output Sheet1**

```html
NRREL

       MRBTS           NRBTS           NRCELL          NRREL           id          cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset         cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset         gNbId           gNbIdLength         gnbPlmn         Item-gnbPlmn-mcc        Item-gnbPlmn-mnc        Item-gnbPlmn-mncLength          handoverAllowedSA           handoverAllowedSARedCap         isRplCellForPSCell          lcrId           nrDcAllowed         removeNotAllowed
277215  277215  0   1   14823863    24  24  277215  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   16  0   1
277215  277215  0   131 14823714    24  24  277240  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   18  0   0
277215  277215  0   132 14823717    24  24  277227  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   18  0   0
277215  277215  0   17  14823804    24  24  277552  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   16  0   0
277215  277215  0   173 14823810    24  24  277234  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   1   0   0
277215  277215  0   180 45703377    24  24  277572  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   2   0   0
```

**Expectedoutput Sheet2**

```html
NRRELE


       MRBTS           NRBTS           NRCELL          NRRELE          id          cellIndividualOffset        eNodeBId        ecgiPlmn        Item-ecgiPlmn-mcc           Item-ecgiPlmn-mnc           Item-ecgiPlmn-mncLength         eutranCellBlacklisted           lcrId           removeNotAllowed
277215  277215  2   91  14823899    24  28495   List    405 854 3   0   49  1
277215  277215  2   92  14823900    24  22523   List    405 854 3   0   22  1
277215  277215  2   93  14823901    24  8612    List    405 854 3   0   49  1
277215  277215  2   94  14823903    24  26480   List    405 854 3   0   36  1
277215  277215  2   95  14823887    24  7948    List    405 854 3   0   16  1
277215  277215  2   96  14823888    24  32  List    405 854 3   0   50  1
```

***CODE1***

```html
    #extracting the xml data
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd; import re

root = ET.parse("test.xml")

out = {}
for mo in root.findall(".//{*}managedObject"):
    tmp = dict(
        re.findall(r"([^/]+?)-([^/]+)", mo.attrib["distName"])[1:],
        id=mo.attrib["id"],
        **{ele.attrib["name"]: ele.text if ((tn:=ele.tag.split("}")[-1]) == "p")
           else tn for ele in mo.findall(".//")  if ele.attrib.get("name")},
    )
    
    out.setdefault(mo.attrib["class"], []).append(tmp)

#Writing to excel
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
    for k,v in out.items():
        (pd.DataFrame(v).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
             .to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k, index=False))

# to access one of the dataframes, use dict-indexing (e.g `dfs["NRREL"]`)
dfs = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in out.items()}
```

***CODE2***

```html
##ALTERNATE TO ABOVE
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd; import re

with open("test.xml") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "xml")

out = {}
for mo in soup.select("managedObject"):
    tmp = dict(
        re.findall(r"([^/]+?)-([^/]+)", mo["distName"])[1:], id=mo["id"],
        **{t["name"]: t.get_text() for t in mo.select("p")},
        **{(t:=mo.select(":not(p)")[0])["name"]: t.name}
    )
 
    out.setdefault(mo["class"], []).append(tmp)
    
with pd.ExcelWriter("output_all.xlsx") as writer:
    for k,v in out.items():
        (pd.DataFrame(v).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
             .to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k, index=False))
        
dfs = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in out.items()}
```

Above are the two codes which was helped by Timeleee...im unable to tag him for credit

Comment: Could you provide some additional info please. What is the memory of your computer? Does it crash while reading / parsing or while writing? What does crashing means, is there an error message?

Comment: Windows10 PC,8GB RAM(6.82GB usable),64 Bit ,AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics 2.10 GHz

Answer (score 3):

To conserve memory you can make streaming parser (for example with standard `html.parser`):

```py
import re
from html.parser import HTMLParser

import pandas as pd


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = {}
        self.current = None
        self.list_name = None
        self.p_name = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)

        if tag == "managedobject":
            self.current = dict(re.findall(r"([^/]+?)-([^/]+)", attrs["distname"])[1:])
            self.data.setdefault(attrs["class"], []).append(self.current)
        elif tag == "list":
            self.list_name = attrs["name"]
        elif tag == "p":
            if self.list_name:
                self.p_name = f'Item-{self.list_name}-{attrs["name"]}'
            else:
                self.p_name = attrs["name"]

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "managedobject":
            self.current = None
        elif tag == "list":
            self.list_name = None
        elif tag == "p":
            self.p_name = None

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if not self.current:
            return

        if self.p_name is not None:
            self.current[self.p_name] = data


parser = MyHTMLParser()
with open("data.xml", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        parser.feed(line)
parser.close()

# here I print it on screen - but save the dataframes to Excel etc.
for k, v in parser.data.items():
    print("Sheet name:", k)
    print("-" * 80)
    df = pd.DataFrame(v)
    print(df)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Sheet name: NRREL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MRBTS   NRBTS NRCELL NRREL cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset   gNbId gNbIdLength Item-gnbPlmn-mcc Item-gnbPlmn-mnc Item-gnbPlmn-mncLength handoverAllowedSA handoverAllowedSARedCap isRplCellForPSCell lcrId nrDcAllowed removeNotAllowed
0  277215  277215      0     1                          24                          24  277215          22              405              854                      3                 1                       0                  0    16           0                1
1  277215  277215      0   131                          24                          24  277240          22              405              854                      3                 1                       0                  0    18           0                0
2  277215  277215      0   132                          24                          24  277227          22              405              854                      3                 1                       0                  0    18           0                0
3  277215  277215      0    17                          24                          24  277552          22              405              854                      3                 1                       0                  0    16           0                0
4  277215  277215      0   173                          24                          24  277234          22              405              854                      3                 1                       0                  0     1           0                0
5  277215  277215      0   180                          24                          24  277572          22              405              854                      3                 1                       0                  0     2           0                0

Sheet name: NRRELE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MRBTS   NRBTS NRCELL NRRELE cellIndividualOffset eNodeBId Item-ecgiPlmn-mcc Item-ecgiPlmn-mnc Item-ecgiPlmn-mncLength eutranCellBlacklisted lcrId removeNotAllowed
0  277215  277215      2     91                   24    28495               405               854                       3                     0    49                1
1  277215  277215      2     92                   24    22523               405               854                       3                     0    22                1
2  277215  277215      2     93                   24     8612               405               854                       3                     0    49                1
3  277215  277215      2     94                   24    26480               405               854                       3                     0    36                1
4  277215  277215      2     95                   24     7948               405               854                       3                     0    16                1
5  277215  277215      2     96                   24       32               405               854                       3                     0    50                1
```

Comment: thanks Andrej...though it took 12mins with RAM getting utilised to 96%,it didnt crash my PC and i did get the output for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iterparse()` from  `xml.etree.ElementTree` and `clear()` the processed nodes from memory:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd


def trans_attrb(node):
    # create dictionary from attrib distName string
    dName = node.attrib
    dsplit = dict(x.split("-") for x in node.get('distName').split("/"))
    del dName['distName']
    dName.update(dsplit)
    for k,v in dName.items():
        dName[k] = [v]
    return dName

def merge_dict(dict_lis):
    new_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for d in (att_list):
        for key, value in d.items():
            new_dict[key].extend(value)
    return dict(new_dict)


att_list = []
name_list = []
d = {}
nsmap = {}
point_of_interesst = ['NRREL'] # change here to 'NRRELE' for other Excel

for event, node in ET.iterparse('test.xml', events=['start-ns', 'end']):
    
    if event == 'start-ns':
        ns, url = node
        nsmap[ns] = url
    

    if event == 'end' and node.tag == f"{{{url}}}managedObject" and node.get('class') in point_of_interesst:
        att_list.append(trans_attrb(node))  
        for dat in node.iter():
            if dat.tag == f"{{{url}}}p" and dat.get('name'):
                if dat.get('name') not in name_list and dat.get('name') is not None:
                    name_list.append(dat.get('name'))
                if dat.get('name') in name_list and dat.get('name') not in d:
                    d[dat.get('name')] = [dat.text]
                if dat.get('name') in name_list and dat.get('name') in d:
                    d[dat.get('name')].append(dat.text)
        node.clear()

data1 = merge_dict(att_list)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) # managedObject attributes
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns= name_list) # embbeded nodes
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(df_concat)

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:  
    df_concat.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

Answer (score -1):

When you have a huge Xml File you need to use XmlReader.  I took my code that I used on your Dec 30 posting and modified to work with XmlReader using Powershell

```
using assembly System.Xml 
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$xmlFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$csvFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$settings = [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings]::new()
$settings.DtdProcessing = [System.Xml.DtdProcessing]::Ignore

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($xmlFilename, $settings)

$reader.MoveToContent();
$nsStr =  $reader.NamespaceURI;
$ns = [System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace]::Get($nsStr)

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

While(-not $reader.EOF)
{
    if($reader.Name -ne 'managedObject')
    {
        $reader.ReadToFollowing('managedObject') | out-null;
    }
    if(-not $reader.EOF)
    {
        $managedObject = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement][System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader);
        $class = $managedObject.Attribute('class').Value
        $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
           Class = $class
        }

        $distName = $managedObject.Attribute('distName').Value
        $distNameArray = $distName.Split('/') | foreach { $obj = $_.Split('-'); $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $obj[0] -NotePropertyValue $obj[1] }
   
        $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName id -NotePropertyValue $managedObject.Attribute('id').Value

        $managedObject.Descendants($ns + 'p') | foreach { $name = $_.Attribute('name').Value; $value = $_.Value; $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $name -NotePropertyValue $value }

        $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
    }
}

$table
$table | Export-CSV -Path $csvFilename -NoTypeInformation

$classes = $table | Group-Object -Property Class

$classes | foreach { $_.Group | Format-Table }
```

Here is the results

```
Class PLMN MRBTS  NRBTS  NRCELL NRREL id       cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset gNbId
----- ---- -----  -----  ------ ----- --       --------------------------- --------------------------- -----
NRREL PLMN 277215 277215 0      1     14823863 24                          24                          277215
NRREL PLMN 277215 277215 0      131   14823714 24                          24                          277240
NRREL PLMN 277215 277215 0      132   14823717 24                          24                          277227



Class  PLMN MRBTS  NRBTS  NRCELL NRRELE id       cellIndividualOffset eNodeBId mcc
-----  ---- -----  -----  ------ ------ --       -------------------- -------- ---
NRRELE PLMN 277215 277215 2      95     14823887 24                   7948     405
NRRELE PLMN 277215 277215 2      96     14823888 24                   32       405
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, as this is an alternative approach to the tags, which may not be understood by everyone. To what extent can it resolve the issue of insufficient memory or counteract the behaviour? Thanks

Comment: I'm unsure as to how useful a PowerShell script will be for a Python question.

Comment: @HedgeHog I've been using XmlReader for years to solve Out Of Memory Issues.  It has never failed even with XML large than 1GB.

Comment: @jdweng That sounds good in principle, but it leaves me with the impression that it is not possible to explain why this is the case and how this approach of all things should be a solution to the problem. Is there a comprehensible description of how the approach manages it compared to the one chosen by the OP?

Comment: @HedgeHog : My code works and the OPs doesn't.

Comment: Powershell is not allowed in my company laptop....

Comment: It comes with windows. May be installed.  Try going to Start button and type Powershell.  It is located in folder C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0